# Ruby: Iterate thought all .rb (including subfolders) files in the folder

Tags: ruby

Files structure:

```
folderA/
 - folder1/
   - file1.rb
   - file2.rb
 - folder2/
   - folder1/
     - file1.rb
   - folder2/
     - file1.rb
 - file1.rb
 - file2.rb
```

With code below i can iterate only on `folderA/file1.rb` and `folderA/file2.rb`

```
# EDITTED
Dir.glob('folderA/*.rb') do |file|
  puts file
end
```

Is it possible to iterate over all `.rb` files (including subfolders) within only using `glob` (without Dir.foreach(dir)..if..)?

**P.S.** Ruby v.1.8.6

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
Dir.glob('folderA/**/*.rb') do |file|
  puts file
end
```

From official [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob):

> **
>   Matches directories recursively.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Dir.glob('spec/**/*.rb') do |rspec_file|
  puts rspec_file
end
```

read [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob) about glob

Comment: weird, this is not new: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/Dir.html#method-c-glob

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

Source here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html

```
require 'find'

Find.find('spec/') do |rspec_file|
    next if FileTest.directory?(rspec_file)
    if /.*\.rb/.match(File.basename(rspec_file))
        puts rspec_file
    end
end
```

Tested in ruby 1.8.7

Comment: You could always remove it.  Just don't name directories in the form <blah.rb