# How to change a cheezy page object class to a subfolder of pages

Tags: cucumber, pageobjects, page-object-gem

I have a cucumber project that uses Cheezy Page Objects.

Everything is working fine but as I was already with too many page object classes I decided to move them from the /pages folder to some subfolders (/pages/homepage, /pages/checkout_page).

The problem is that now the steps don't recognize the classes (I get the error Homepage not found). I'm sure this is a simple question, but how can I make this work?

Thanks

Also, I have this on the env.rb

```
  Dir[$PROJECT_ROOT + '/pages/*.rb'].each {|file| require file }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I found the solution here: [Ruby: Iterate thought all .rb (including subfolders) files in the folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798994/ruby-iterate-thought-all-rb-including-subfolders-files-in-the-folder)

I needed to change

```
Dir[$PROJECT_ROOT + '/pages/*.rb'].each {|file| require file }
```

to

```
Dir[$PROJECT_ROOT + '/pages/**/*.rb'].each {|file| require file }
```

Thaks anyway :)